# Use jQuery to swap headers with animation on scroll down, and swap back on scroll up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've found a lot of info. on changing headers when scrolling with jQuery and have tried to adapt a few to make them fit my needs. Scolling down works fine, but scrolling up does nothing. Any ideas? Here's what I have so far:

HTML/CSS:

```
<header id="pictogram">
    <ul id="nav-main">
        <li><a href="#"><span>A</span><img src="A.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>B</span><img src="B.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>C</span><img src="C.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>D</span><img src="D.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<header id="nopictogram" style="opacity:0;display:none;">
    <ul id="nav-main">
        <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Beautifully</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Challenging</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Day</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

jQuery:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st < lastScrollTop){

            $('header#nopictogram')
                .animate({'opacity':'0'},500, 
                    function(){$('header#nopictogram')
                    .css({'display':'none'});
                    });
            $('header#pictogram')
                .css({'display':'block'})
                .animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        } else {

            $('header#pictogram')
                .animate({'opacity':'0'},500, 
                    function(){$('header#pictogram')
                    .css({'display':'none'});
                    });
            $('header#nopictogram')
                .css({'display':'block'})
                .animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        } //end if

        lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5Lco8f6/5/).

Comment: add the relevant HTML and CSS as well please

Comment: and preferably a fiddle as well thanks

Comment: So when you scroll down you want the images to disappear and the links navigation to appear and when you scroll back to top you want the images to reappear and the links nav to disappear. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Scroll down: header#pictogram to disappear & header#nopictogram to appear.
Scroll back to top: header#nopictogram to disappear & header#pictogram to reappear

Comment: when should the pictogram should appear. when you reach top or directly when you scroll top direction ?

Comment: @Dwza - #pictogram should reappear when the user reaches the top of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/q5Lco8f6/7/

I'm not sure what you are trying to track with lastScrollTop. When scrollTop is 0, your at the top of the page. When it is not 0, you are not at the top.

So, when 0, show picto. When not 0, show nopicto.

Also, you are jumbling opacity and display none and causing weird visibility states. Just use fadeIn fadeOut, and set nopicto to just display:none in css.

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (st == 0 && $('header#nopictogram').is(':visible')) {
        $('header#nopictogram').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $('header#pictogram').fadeIn(500);
        });        
    } 
    else if ($('header#pictogram').is(':visible')) {
        $('header#pictogram').fadeOut(500, function () {
              $('header#nopictogram').fadeIn(500);
        });        
    } //end if
});
```